# Validation not working right

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to get my validate to work upon clicking my submit button. I don't want the fade out to occur unless everything in the form is right. My validation works on the page, but not when clicking the submit button..I don't want it to use my hide function unless the whole form is validated correctly. Here is my code. Anything here that jumps out to you guys? Fixed the wording of the question :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $.supersized({
            //Background image
            slides  :  [ { image : 'images/pendulumWeb.jpg' } ]                 
        });

        $("form[name=emailSubmit]").validate({
            rules: {
                title: {
                    required: true
                },
                fName: {
                    required: true
                },
                lName: {
                    required: true
                },
                profession: {
                    required: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                phone: {
                    number: true
                }

            },
            messages: {
                title: {
                    required: "Please enter your title."
                },
                fName: {
                    required: "Please enter your first name"
                },
                lName: {
                    required: "Please enter your last name."
                },
                profession: {
                    required: "Please enter your profession"
                },
                email: {
                    required: "Please enter your email"
                }
            }
        });

        $("form#emailSubmit").submit(function() {
            // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
            var title = $('#title').attr('value');
            var fName = $('#fName').attr('value');
            var lName = $('#lName').attr('value');
            var profession = $('#profession').attr('value');
            var email = $('#email').attr('value');
            var phone = $('#phone').attr('value');
            var message = $('#message').attr('value');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    data: "title="+ title +"& fName="+ fName +"& lName="+ lName +"& profession="+ profession +"& email="+ email +"& phone="+ phone +"& message="+ message,
                    success: function(){
                         $('form#emailSubmit').hide(0,function() {
                            $('div#contact').fadeOut('fast  ');
                            $('div.success').fadeIn(3000);
                        });
                    }
                });
            return false;
            });

            $('#contact').animate({height: '+=600px'}, 3000, 'easeInOutExpo');
            $('#content').fadeIn(6000);


        });


</script>
```

Here is my html

```
<body>

<form id="emailSubmit" name="emailSubmit" method="post">
    <div id="submit">
        <table>
            <tr style="height: 20px;">
                <td><span class="formTitles">Title*</span></td>
                <td><input id="title" name="title" value="" size="5" max="3" type="text" />
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 20px;">
                <td><span class="formTitles">First Name*</span></td>
                <td><input id="fName" name="fName" value="" size="20" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 20px;">
                <td><span class="formTitles">Last Name*</span></td>
                <td><input id="lName" name="lName" value="" size="20" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 20px;">
                <td><span class="formTitles">Profession*</span> </td>
                <td><input id="profession" name="profession" value="" size="20" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 20px;">
                <td><span class="formTitles">Email*</span> </td>
                <td><input id="email" name="email" value="" size="20" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 20px;">
                <td><span class="formTitles">Phone</span></td>
                <td><input id="phone" name="phone" value="" size="20" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 20px;">
                <td><span class="formTitles">Message</span></td>
                <td><textarea name="message" id="message" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="formTitles"></span></td>
                <td><button class="buttonPositive" type="submit"> Submit</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </div>
</form>

<div id="contact">
    <div id="content" style="display: none;">

    </div>
</div>

    <div class="success" style="display: none;">
    </div>
```

Comment: I disagree with "drive-by downvotes" unaccompanied by explanation. It's not clear, however, what you mean by "up front".  What does happen when you click the button?  Does the HTTP transaction take place? Are there JavaScript or server errors reported?

Comment: Initially when filling the form out, if I fill out the fields with the wrong information, my rules come up or error messages come up. Upon clicking my submit button though, the hide method goes into effect along with my callback. I don't want the hide method to go into effect unless the entire form has right information according to my rules set. There are no errors on my console and my data is being submitted to my db.

Comment: Can anybody help? I really am stumped here. I was thinking my code is in the wrong order. I tried rearranging it only to get an unexpected token error. I moved my form.submit code right below my validate under messages, but no dice.

Comment: Well you're not doing anything in the "submit()" handler to trigger a validation pass.

Comment: How would I go about setting that up? Forgive me but I haven't done much validation.

Comment: OK I typed in an answer below. Sorry about the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to have taken so long; I had to go to an opera.  The way to check form validity explicitly is to call ".valid()" and check the result; it returns `true` if the form is valid according to the rules you set up at initialization time:

```
    $("form#emailSubmit").submit(function() {
        if (!$(this).valid()) {
          alert("Naughty naughty!");
          return false;
        }

        // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
        ...
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you for your help, much appreciated :) I didn't know about the valid method.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you souhld use the same selector for both event :

```
$("form[name=emailSubmit]").validate({

$("form#emailSubmit").submit(function() {
```

By the way, when using selector with "id" (emailSubmit), you don't need to use the tag (form) selector. In former versions of jquery (<1.4 if i remember well), it was even slower.

Eventually, i do not well understand :

> My validation up front works, but not
>   when clicking the submit button.

What do you mean by validation up front VS clicking ?

Regards,

Max

Comment: Well when initially filling the form out, if I fill out the fields with the wrong information. The error messages do come up. Upon clicking my submit button though, the hide method goes into effect along with my callback. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot that the validate worked before the submit and i now understand your point. Pointy answered your question so tell us if it still does not work.